# Refactoring Project : List all functions in class library with parameters

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, refactoring

I am looking at a project that requires me to allow a stack of data access functions to be accessible via a web service. At the moment the code is in DAL classes in the .net code. Is there a utility out there that can parse a dll; and export all the functions in the class library with the parameters/ types?

Comment: Is that a .net assembly? If yes you can easily reflect it using reflection.

Comment: have you tried googling `jetBeans` it's a good tool to do that as long as the assmeblies are managed / written in .net code

Comment: You can also open it in ILSpy, select a node and then **FILE Menu | Save Code**  It will save to .CS or .VB depending on which view you have selected in the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Using Redgate Reflector I was to able to easily extract to text a list of functions from a class. I can then use to build a web service wrapper for those functions.